# 'finding' or 'discovery'

Tags: word-choice, tech-writing

I am writing a scientific paper on physics. I hesitate to write that my observations and their interpretation is a 'discovery', so I am considering using the word 'finding' instead.

Is this the common practice?

Comment: It is alright to use "finding" here.

Comment: A *finding* is something you found to be true. A *discovery*, for your science, is a finding that no one has found before. (Whether a finding is a discovery for you personally, but not for your science, is usually considered irrelevant for a scientific paper. What counts is the significance for the science.)

Comment: Similar question : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40793/difference-between-find-out-discover-realize-and-etc

Answer (score 1):

Although in a general linguistic sense the two are more or less equivalent, for scientific writing you are correct in thinking ‘discovery’ would sound too pretentious. ‘Finding’ is quite suitable in Physics as in other sciences, as indicated by its frequent use in papers in a single issue of [Nature Physics](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v12/n5/index.html) that I have just consulted. Each of the following is from a different paper.

> Our *findings* provide solid experimental and theoretical frameworks for future investigations of the origin and function of active motion in cells.
>
> Our *findings* lay the groundwork for further improving efficiency, with 15% energy coupling predicted in FI experiments using an existing megajoule-scale laser driver.
>
> Rather, this *finding* suggests a mixed Ti3+/4+ character for the bilayers, with an increase of the Ti valence towards 4+ for smaller rare-earths in the nickelate.

The single occurrence I found of the word ‘discovery’ was in an introduction reviewing the general progress in the field. I would wait until you find a new elementary particle or the like before using ‘discovery’.